# Maximum Request Length Exceeded Errors

Tags: asp.net, iis

I read the book ASP.NET MVS with Entity Framework and CSS. And I can't solve some problem with dealing maximum Request Length Exceeded Errors. I edit the system.web section and add the maxRequestLength:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="20480"/>
```

When files exceed 20 Mb I get the error "Maximum Request Length Exceeded".
Then I update system.webServer:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="20971520"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

And at this point I don't have any errors when files exceed the limit. The browser just wait for a long time and nothing happens. I want to add Custom Error Page for Maximum Request Length.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
<remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13"/>
<error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" responseMode="Redirect" path="/Error/FileUploadLimitExceeded"/>
</httpErrors>
```

But it also doesn't work. I think it because of requestFiltering. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set both `httpRuntime.maxRequestLength` and requestFiltering.maxAllowedContentLength`.

Something like this

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime
            maxRequestLength="512000"
            executionTimeout="3600"
        />
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Source: https://forums.iis.net/t/1169846.aspx

Comment: Yes. I put all three: maxRequestLength, maxAllowedContentLength and httpErrors. And in the end i should get redirection to my custom error page, when 404.13 error occurs. But nothing happens. I think something wrong with iis. But i cant find the answer.